# Behind the Washer and Dryer clearance

Tags: washing-machine

I have a 90s GE filter flo heavy capacity top loader washing machine that has started to make squeaky noises during the agitation. It's 27 inches wide and 24 inches in depth.

I'm looking to replace it with another top load machine. The ones I found online are at least 26 inches in depth. My laundry closet is only 29 inches deep. Is 3 inches behind enough for clearance? The old machine has 5 inches behind. What is the minimum size required? I see some front loaders that are 24-25 inches deep but the capacity of those machines are very small.

Comment: If you're getting a new matching washer and dryer, pay attention to the clearance for the dryer as well.  The dryer duct tends to require much more clearance than the water and drain connections for the washer.

Answer (score 1):

The installation clearances for an appliance would be documented in the users manual or installation setup guide.

If you know the manufacturer and exact model number it is very possible to find these manuals and/or guides online. Another possibility is to go to the store where you would purchase the appliance and query with the staff there to look at the manuals or just ask their technicians the respective questions.